# Параллелизм и сеть

Tags: многопоточность, сеть, распараллеливание

Допустим, есть какая-то шара на которой лежат файлы мелкого размера(например, 500кб).

Собственно, вопрос, будет ли выигрыш в производительности если их скачивать параллельно имея широкий канал?

Или сетевая карта будет превращать все в 1 поток и параллельно качая файлы пусть и малого размера, будет рубиться общая скорость, что не повысит производительность?

Comment: Можно попробовать, это не сложно) тут помимо ширины канала есть ещё несколько неизвестных, например мощность сервера, удаленность сервера, ПО которое обрабатывает запросы. Когда я делал параллельную загрузку файлов с одного сервиса, который поддерживал http range, тестирование показало что это не эффективно. Оказалось что тестовые сервера это слабенькие виртуалки, на проде наблюдалось заметное усклрнние

Comment: Если шара - это несколько серверов за cdn, то выиграш вполне может быть.

Comment: Например, если клиент захочет скачать по HTTP(S) 100 файлов по 500KB в 10 потоков с keep-alive, то выигрыш некоторый вполне может быть, это зависит от многих факторов. От сервера, например.

Comment: Что такое "шара" ? FTP, HTTP, NFS-udp, NFS-tcp, CIFS ?

Comment: @Борис, какой-то ресурс на который есть доступ и откуда можно скачать файлы. Виндовая расшаренная папка, вроде-TCP протокол.

Comment: @iluxa1810, неужели за 10 дней сами еще не померили?

Comment: @avp я полагаю, тут суть получить концептуальный ответ. Померить многое можно, труднее доказать, что результаты измерений имеют смысл, т.к. результаты могут быть искажены кэшированием или аппаратными сбоями

Comment: вот на msdn недавно обсуждалось то же самое для http, может будет полезно https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/0d621a5f-1687-4834-a1a7-bf64c136480f/c-net-45-?forum=aspnetru

Comment: @VadimTagil, концептуально в комментариях сразу ответили (что зависит от многих факторов...)

Answer (score 1):

Вы копаете не в ту сторону. Особой разницы в производительности при скачивании в один поток или множество не будет, т.к. узким местом в настоящее время является дисковая подсистема (IO-операции).

Многие крупные проекты (например, тот же Facebook или VK) используют обращение напрямую. То есть они не хранят данные в виде множества мелких файлов в системе (при этом в процессе их чтения совершается много лишних операций, которые снижают общую производительность и убивают диски при высокой нагрузке), а пишут все в один большой blob-файл и извлекают из него данные по смещению и размеру. Плюс такие динамические файлы обычно кэшируются.

Что касается многопоточности при передаче файлов, то когда идет запрос на множественное скачивание - на диске идут операции чтения, которые и составляют основное время запроса. Передача данных на широком канале происходит в разы быстрее, чем их чтение с диска. Особой разницы не будет как их передавать - в один поток или множество.

Answer (score 0):

В 2006 MS выпустила утилиту `RichCopy`, которая является продолжением приложения командной строки `RoboCopy`. Эти утилиты предназначены для копирования и перемещения файлов в больших объемах, в том числе и по протоколу `SMB`. Одна из ключевых опций `RichCopy` - это многопоточное копирование файлов. И да, использование этой функции дает прирост в скорости копирования.

При современном развитии сетей "бутылочное горлышко" сместилось от сетевой подсистемы к дисковой. Использование многопоточности позволяет "убрать" время операций открытия/чтения/закрытия файлов из общего времени копирования по сети.

Answer (score 0):

При скачивании в несколько потоков производительность будет выигрывать в том случае если будет мало обращений к серверу, но если к серверу будут обращаться одновременно много людей то производительность ляжет на нет(если не сам сервер).